# why is is_regular_file reporting true for symbolic link

Tags: c++, symlink, std-filesystem

Why is it that `is_regular_file` function that is part of `std::filesystem` reports true for a symbolic link? I have looked at the documentation for the call and can't find the reason and the examples on cppreference exhibit the same behaviour.

As an example, if we look at the binary `pidof`; It exists as `/usr/sbin/pidof` and correctly labelled as a symbolic link as shown here by `stat`:

```
[@rhel9 ~]$ stat /usr/sbin/pidof 
  File: /usr/sbin/pidof -> /usr/bin/pidof
  Size: 14          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 34952482    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
Access: 2024-02-05 15:46:24.124158991 +0000
Modify: 2023-01-28 09:40:21.000000000 +0000
Change: 2023-05-09 17:34:59.432002380 +0100
 Birth: 2023-05-09 17:34:59.432002380 +0100
```

If we follow the link and run `stat` on it:

```
[@rhel9 ~]$ stat /usr/bin/pidof 
  File: /usr/bin/pidof
  Size: 23760       Blocks: 48         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 18153014    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
Access: 2024-02-02 15:12:41.804334284 +0000
Modify: 2023-01-28 09:40:21.000000000 +0000
Change: 2023-05-09 17:34:59.418002380 +0100
 Birth: 2023-05-09 17:34:59.417002380 +0100
```

If we run the following code:

```
const std::filesystem::path fsBin("/usr/sbin/pidof");
if (true == std::filesystem::is_regular_file(fsBin))
{
    std::cout << "Regular File" << std::endl;
}
else if(true == std::filesystem::is_symlink(fsBin))
{
    std::cout << "Symbolic Link" << std::endl;
}
```

The code always prints "Regular File" despite the path being a symbolic link. If I switch the cases around (have `is_symlink` as the first check), it reports correctly that it is a symlink. What is interesting too is that if I use a `std::filesystem::status` objects instead of the `std::filesystem::path`, it never reports a symlink regardless of the order.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour that I'm maybe overlooking?

Comment: By "regular file" probably they mean that symlink supports all the API functions that regular file does, so normally your app should not care is it symlink or actually a file. And that is good, from my point of view. You create a symlink and you are sure that your app will work exactly the same as if that was a file.

Comment: C++ fs API is analogous to POSIX API, with [`filesystem::status()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.op.status) corresponding to POSIX [`stat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/stat.html) and [`filesystem::symlink_status()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.op.symlink.status) corresponding to POSIX [`lstat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/lstat.html). [`is_regular_file()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/fs.op.is.regular.file) uses the result of `status()`, and `is_symlink()` uses the result of `symlink_status()`, so that the results are as presented by OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file), the function

```
bool std::filesystem::is_regular_file(const std::filesystem::path& p);
```

is equivalent to

```
std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::status(p))
```

where the [`std::filesystem::status`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/status) function

> Determines the type and attributes of the filesystem object identified by `p` as if by POSIX `stat` (**symlinks are followed to their targets**).

Whereas the `std::filesystem::symlink_status` function

> is the same as the `std::filesystem::status` function, except that the behavior is as if the POSIX `lstat` is used (**symlinks are not followed**).

Thus, the correct usage in your case would be:

```
if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(std::filesystem::symlink_status(fsBin)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: interesting and an important point I missed when going over the documentation. Changing the code to match your example fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

`is_regular_file(path)` answers: is this a regular file *after following symlinks*? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file)

`is_symlink(path)` answers: is this a symlink? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink)

Note the subtle distinction that `is_regular_file` uses `status` which follows symlinks and `is_symlink` uses `symlink_status` which does not.

Comment: Where does it say that on the cppreference page?

Comment: Ah, I see that now when reading the documentation after reading the comments. `is_regular_file` is using `status` whereas `is_symlink` is using `symlink_status` and won't follow the link through.

Comment: @user17732522 fair enough that it's subtle, added a bit more text.